# PnP Cmdlet doesnt reslove Connection Parameter right

Tags: powershell

i have been trying to add a js link using Add-PnPJavaScriptLink

```
$jsLinkAddJquery = "Add-PnPJavaScriptLink -Name 'jquery' -Url '/SiteAssets/jquery-3.4.1.min.js' -Connection $($Global:PnPConnection)"
Invoke-Expression $jsLinkAddJquery
```

but i get the exception:

```
Cannot bind parameter 'Connection'. Cannot convert the "PnP.PowerShell.Commands.Base.PnPConnection" value of 
type "System.String" to type "PnP.PowerShell.Commands.Base.PnPConnection".
```

How can i resolve the Connection Variable right?

Comment: Maybe invoke-expression isn't the best way to run things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue comes from the *stringifying* of `$PnPConnection`. You're evaluating it before the actual invocation of the command via `Invoke-Expression`. You have to tell it to not evaluate it while in string format with the simplest way being by swapping the quotes to single quotes:

```
$jsLinkAddJquery = 'Add-PnPJavaScriptLink -Name "jquery" -Url "/SiteAssets/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" -Connection $PnPConnection'
Invoke-Expression $jsLinkAddJquery
```